# Help me Using jScrollPane - JQUERY Plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane

I download and using Jscrollpane at http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ but it not work well after i dit my html code and css as example with customize suitable with my situation, it do not display scroll bar here :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.menu-meal li .meal-content').jScrollPane({
            showArrows: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

here my html :

```
<ul class="menu-meal">
<li>
    <div class="meal-name">
        <img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Menu1_img_MealName_Breakfast" src="Images/MealName_Breakfast.png" style="border-width:0px;" />
    </div>

    <div class="meal-content">
        <h1>
            <span class="meal-title">BREAKFAST & LUNCH</span>
        </h1>
        <p class="meal-sub-title">
            BREAKFAST( FROM 7AM-10:30AM)
        </p>
        <p class="food">

            <span class="food-name">01.TRADITIONAL BEEF NOODLE SOUP</span> <span class="food-price">
                23.4</span>
        </p>
        <p class="food">
            <span class="food-name">02.RICE NOODLE SOUP WITH CRISPY SOFT SHELL CRAB AND LIME LEAVE</span>
            <span class="food-price">28.5</span>

        </p>
        <p class="food">
            <span class="food-name">03.RICE NOODLE SOUP WITH MUSHROOM AND SEAFOOD</span> <span
                class="food-price">22.8</span>
        </p>
        <p class="food">
            <span class="food-name">04.AMERICAN BREAFAST: CHOICE OF FRIED EGG OR OMELETE SERVED</span>
            <span class="food-price"></span>

        </p>           
    </div>
</li></ul>
```

and here my css code :

```
.main-content ul.menu-meal
{
    background-color: #dbd8d0;
    float: left;
    height: 800px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1160px;
}

ul.menu-meal li
{
    background-color: #dbd8d0;
    /*cursor: pointer;*/
    height: 800px;
    padding-right: 280px; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 880px;
}

ul.menu-meal li div.meal-name
{
    float: left;
    background-color: #817d6d;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.menu-meal li.active div.meal-name, ul.menu-meal li:hover div.meal-name
{
    background: url(../Images/Bg_Menu_Meal_Name.png) repeat-y left top;   
} 

div.meal-name img
{
    border: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.menu-meal li div.meal-content
{
    float: left;
    height: 740px;
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 80px;
    position: relative;
    width: 730px;
    overflow: auto;
}

div.meal-content h1
{
    float: left;
    width: 730px;
}

div.meal-content p.food, div.meal-content p.meal-sub-category
{
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 700px;
}

div.meal-content p.food .food-name
{
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

div.meal-content p.food .food-name b
{
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

div.meal-content p.food .food-price
{
    float: right;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
```

please help me using it. at my using it just display jspHorizontalBar, jspContainer, jspPane . jspPane in jspContainer but it not wrap my content, my content overflow out of jspPane area, and jspVerticalBar do not display, i want display jspVerticalBar not jspHorizontalBar. Help me !

Comment: Please provide a link to your page (or to a copy of your page on http://jsfiddle.net ) - this will make it much easier for someone to help you debug...

Answer (score 0):

set a height/min-height (to confirm its working, set this height smaller then your elements) on your container and try to set overflow: auto; or overflow: scroll; i cant really remember right now, and you didnt posted a jsfiddle :(